# brakeman is throwing Unescaped model attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, brakeman

I have a code in a erb file like this

```
<% unless (rem_cust = RemCust.find_by_acc_id(curr_acc.id)) %>
<% else %>
<p><%= t("translate", :del => formated_date(2.days.since(rem_cust.created_at), {:format => :short_day_with_week, :include_year => true})).html_safe %></p>
<% end %>
```

When I run brakeman I get a warning like "Unescaped model attribute" and the type is "Cross-Site Scripting".

I tried to add `ERB::Util.html_escape(rem_cust.created_at)` but that didn't make the warning go away. I believe it must have something to do with the earlier line.

Comment: I would worry more about `unless (rem_cust = RemCust.find_by_acc_id(curr_acc.id))`. That means the next line should only run  if the return value is falsy. That means its a guaranteed NoMethod error since only nil and false are falsy. Assignment in conditions is also super icky.

Comment: that wasn't the full code I have added the relevant sections